# How to save versions of the project in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, version-control, xcode5

I'm new here.
I created a project and edited it few times. to back up I made a copy of the project folder. I see that in the Xcode 5 appears Source Control and I try to use it for my project versions back up. I selected from the menu: Source Control > Check Out - and entered a Repository Location => it created an empty project (with my project name). How can I save versions of a project?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not relying on xcode's built-in version control.

Try out http://github.com

Comment: I disagree, Xcode integration with Git is good. In addition I use Tower, mainly to keep track of remote repositories.

Comment: My question indeed regarded the built-in version control of Xcode. I see that github is external to Xcode. Can you or anyone please recommend a tutorial for the Xcode versions source control?

Comment: Sure, the Apple WWDC-13 [session 414](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) Understanding Source Control in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

For local use the building Git is good, commit often.

See, the Apple [WWDC-13](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) session 414 (Understanding Source Control in Xcode) for more information.

For secure off-sit setup a remote repository, [GitHub](https://github.com) is the most popular but not free for private repos. [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) is free for limited private repositories and is easy to use.